# Exploitation Risks and Considerations specific to running internal DNS servers

Tags: dns, denial-of-service, enumeration

I have heard of larger companies are utilizing their own internal DNS servers to route through internal resources. And was wondering if there is any specific exploitation risks and considerations for these, especially related to loss of availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main challenges compared to using a public DNS server are:

- The sensitivity of the information stored in DNS
  These are information about internal resources, which should in many cases not be publicly available. So there is an additional risk that these information might leak if not properly protected. Compared to this a public DNS server stores only information intended for the public anyway.
- The ability to properly run the DNS server
  Most public DNS servers are probably administered more professionally, since there is a lot at stake if DNS is down. Most users don't run their own public DNS server for their own domain but let professionals like hosting providers do this. Compared to this managing the internal DNS servers is often a side job, done by users with only minimal experience in this area. This of course can impact both availability and security.

Apart from these considerations the internal DNS is not inherently less secure than a public DNS. It might even be more secure since one has more control over the operation of the server (as long as not outsourced). Also, availability might be less of a problem: if the internal DNS server is down only a few internal users are affected, compared to the many users affected when a public DNS server does not work.